# Why is my Shiny app not working? ' there is no package called 'tidyverse' '

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, shinyapps

So, I wonder if anyone has a clue about this.

I have an app which works on my computer, but when I try to deploy it using shinyapps.io, I get nothing but an error message.

This is the error message I get:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Halted execution.
```

My session info is:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shinydashboard_0.7.1 sf_0.8-0             plotly_4.9.1         shinythemes_1.1.2   
 [5] vctrs_0.2.0          ggcorrplot_0.1.3     DT_0.10              forcats_0.4.0       
 [9] stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_0.8.3          purrr_0.3.3          readr_1.3.1         
[13] tidyr_1.0.0          tibble_2.1.3         ggplot2_3.2.1        tidyverse_1.3.0     
[17] shiny_1.4.0          rsconnect_0.8.16    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3         lubridate_1.7.4    lattice_0.20-38    class_7.3-15       assertthat_0.2.1  
 [6] zeallot_0.1.0      digest_0.6.23      packrat_0.5.0      mime_0.7           R6_2.4.1          
[11] cellranger_1.1.0   backports_1.1.5    reprex_0.3.0       e1071_1.7-3        httr_1.4.1        
[16] pillar_1.4.2       rlang_0.4.2        lazyeval_0.2.2     curl_4.2           readxl_1.3.1      
[21] data.table_1.12.8  rstudioapi_0.10    htmlwidgets_1.5.1  munsell_0.5.0      broom_0.5.2       
[26] compiler_3.6.1     httpuv_1.5.2       modelr_0.1.5       pkgconfig_2.0.3    askpass_1.1       
[31] htmltools_0.4.0    openssl_1.4.1      tidyselect_0.2.5   viridisLite_0.3.0  crayon_1.3.4      
[36] dbplyr_1.4.2       withr_2.1.2        later_1.0.0        grid_3.6.1         nlme_3.1-140      
[41] jsonlite_1.6       xtable_1.8-4       gtable_0.3.0       lifecycle_0.1.0    DBI_1.0.0         
[46] magrittr_1.5       units_0.6-5        scales_1.1.0       KernSmooth_2.23-15 cli_1.1.0         
[51] stringi_1.4.3      fs_1.3.1           promises_1.1.0     xml2_1.2.2         generics_0.0.2    
[56] tools_3.6.1        glue_1.3.1         hms_0.5.2          fastmap_1.0.1      colorspace_1.4-1  
[61] classInt_0.4-2     rvest_0.3.5        haven_2.2.0
```

Comment: Instead of loading the tidyverse package, which is just a convenience for loading a bunch of other packages, try loading just the ones you actually need to use, e.g. dplyr, stringr, etc. Beyond that, there would need to be more information in the post

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work. It throws the error with any package I try to load the first (except for shiny).

Comment: My app is quite long so I'll try to create another question with a small reproducible example. I suspect the problem may be related to encoding, as I'm using spanish characters.

Comment: Or maybe it is a problem with lib.path

Comment: Is that your session info, or the session info on shinyapps.io?

Comment: It's my session info. My bad. How can I retrieve session info on shinyapps.io?

Comment: I would contact RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your App to `shinyapps.io`, Shiny will search your code and install all the packages that you have loaded in a `library()` function.

When searching the Shiny documentation, you can find this below quote under the [Package Dependencies](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html#package-dependencies) section.

> When you deploy your application, the `rsconnect` package attempts to detect the packages that your application uses. `rsconnect` sends this list of packages and their dependencies along with your application to the shinyapps.io service. Then shinyapps.io builds and installs the packages into the R library for your application. The first time you deploy your application, it may take some time to build these packages (depending on how many packages are used). However, you will not wait for these packages to build during future deployments (unless you upgrade or downgrade a package).

So make sure you explicitly state the packages you require so they can be installed during deployment.